# SQL String comparison with < or >

Tags: sql, string, string-comparison

I'm studying for an exam in database and in one of my exercises I should state whether an `INSERT [...]` is possible for this database:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
   a1 INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   a2 CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   a3 CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   CHECK(a2<a3)
)
```

What does that last bit mean `(a2<a3)`? 
It's a string, so what does it compare, the length or what? Some help would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: My guess is that it's a contstraint meaning that the value of a2 has to be less than the value of a3.  Try inserting a record that does not meet that condition.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It's the [Lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), the same which is used when you use `Order By` on  a text column. So for example `AA` comes before `AB`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`insert into A values (0, 'a', 'b');`
is possible

`insert into A values (1, 'b', 'a');` throws an exception

`CHECK(a2 < a3)` only allows inserts where the value of a2 comes first in the alphabet (is lower), compared to a3.

You can try to execute `select ascii('a');` so you can see the ASCII-code of the character (here: 97).

Edit:
Be aware that capital letters like A has different ascii codes than small modes like a

[Link to an ASCII-code table](http://www.ascii-code.com/)

Comment: This answer is close.  Most databases have something called a *collation* assigned to string values.  The *collation* tells the database how to compare string values.  The default collation is often ASCII ordering but there are definitely other options.  You should check the documentation of the database you are working with for more information.